# Within this function, I should change the methods of calculation of the cost for some of the provinces of Lombardy as listed

Tags: php, function

Within this function, I should change the methods of calculation of the cost for some of the provinces of Lombardy as listed

```
MI: up to 100kg 10,00 EUR over 4 euro per quintal.
MB: up to 100kg 15,00 EUR over 4 euro per quintal.
LC: up to 100kg 15,00 EUR over 4 euro per quintal.
PV: up to 100kg 15,00 EUR over 4 euro per quintal.
CO: up to 100kg 15,00 EUR over 4 euro per quintal.
VA: up to 100kg 15,00 EUR over 4 euro per quintal.
LO: up to 100kg 15,00 EUR over 4 euro per quintal.
BG: up to 100kg 15,00 EUR over 4 euro per quintal.
BS: up to 100kg 25,00 EUR over 4 euro per quintal.
```

In addition to these provinces it should no longer be applied to the extra mileage and volume weight ratio changes from 1 cubic meter = 250 kg per 1 cubic meter = 167 kg.

The calculation is now a hundredweight and not more per kg as before then rounding will always be higher

i try to do it in this mode:

```
function calcola_costo($peso_totale, $volume_totale, $destinazione_stato, $destinazione_province_id, $destinazione_comuni_id, $destinazione_indirizzo, $destinazione_indirizzo_civico, $contrassegno = false){


if(in_array($destinazione_province_id,array(15,108,97,18,13,12,98,16,17))){
    //  Eccezione
    $costo = 0;
    $peso_metro_cubo = 167;
    $costo_primi_50_kg = 6.5;
    $costo_al_kg_oltre_50_kg = 0.04;
    $costo = 0;        

    switch($destinazione_province_id){
        case 15:
            $costo+=
            break;
    }
}else{
    //  Vecchio script
    $costo = 0;
    $peso_metro_cubo = 250;
    $costo_primi_50_kg = 6.5;
    $costo_al_kg_oltre_50_kg = 0.04;

    //  Controllo se mi conviene utilizzare il peso effettivo o quello in base al volume
    //  Ad un metro cubo di merce è associato un peso standard definito nel file di configurazione
    //  Il sistema seleziona la soluzione più pesante perchè più costosa
    //  Il peso di un metro cubo standard è definito in 250Kg
    if($peso_totale>$volume_totale*$peso_metro_cubo){
        $peso = $peso_totale;
    }else{
        $peso = $volume_totale*$peso_metro_cubo;
    }


    //  Aggiungo il costo base dei primi 50Kg
    $costo+= $costo_primi_50_kg;
    //  Se supera i 50 Kg aggiungo il costo per ogni kg extra
    if($peso>50){
        $costo+= ceil($peso-50)*$costo_al_kg_oltre_50_kg;
    }



    //  Calcolo la distanza dal magazzino

    // set URL and other appropriate options
    $partenza = preg_replace('/\s/','+',MAGAZZINO_INDIRIZZO);
    $destinazione_provincia = elimina_accenti(get_province_sigla_from_id($destinazione_province_id));
    $destinazione_comune = elimina_accenti(get_comuni_nome_from_id($destinazione_comuni_id));
    $destinazione_indirizzo = elimina_accenti(str_replace('&#39;', "'", $destinazione_indirizzo));
    $destinazione_indirizzo_civico = elimina_accenti(str_replace('&#39;', "'", $destinazione_indirizzo_civico));
    $destinazione_comune = elimina_accenti(str_replace('&#39;', "'", $destinazione_comune));
    $destinazione_provincia = elimina_accenti(str_replace('&#39;', "'", $destinazione_provincia));
    $destinazione_stato = elimina_accenti(str_replace('&#39;', "'", $destinazione_stato));
    $destinazione = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z\d]+/','+',  $destinazione_indirizzo).','.preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z\d]+/','+',$destinazione_indirizzo_civico).'+'.preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z\d]+/','+',$destinazione_comune).'+'.preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z\d]+/','+',$destinazione_provincia).'+'.preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z\d]+/','+',$destinazione_stato);
    //$destinazione = preg_replace('/\s/','+',$destinazione_comune).'+'.preg_replace('/\s/','+',$destinazione_provincia).'+'.preg_replace('/\s/','+',$destinazione_stato);
    $km = 0;
    if(!is_numeric($km = get_distance($partenza, $destinazione))){
        $destinazione = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z\d]+/','+',$destinazione_comune).'+'.preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z\d]+/','+',$destinazione_provincia).'+'.preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z\d]+/','+',$destinazione_stato);
        if(!is_numeric($km = get_distance($partenza, $destinazione))){
            set_error("Errore nel calcolo della distanza!");
        }
    }
    //  Aggiungo al costo la tariffa kilometrica in base al raggio
    if($km>10 && $km<=15){
        $costo+= 1.3;
    }elseif($km>15 && $km<=20){
        $costo+= 2.6;
    }elseif($km>20 && $km<=25){
        $costo+= 3.9;
    }elseif($km>25 && $km<=30){
        $costo+= 5;
    }elseif($km>30 && $km<=35){
        $costo+= 6.5;
    }elseif($km>35 && $km<=40){
        $costo+= 7.8;
    }elseif($km>40 && $km<=45){
        $costo+= 9;
    }elseif($km>45 && $km<=60){
        $costo+= 10;
    }elseif($km>60 && $km<=70){
        $costo+= 15.5;
    }elseif($km>70){
        $costo+= 15.5;
        //  Vanno aggiunti 50 cent per ogni kilometro oltre i 70
        $costo+= ($km-70)*0.5;
    }

    //  Costo aggiuntivo se pagamento in contrassegno
    if($contrassegno){
        $costo+= 1.5;
    }

}
return number_format($costo,2,'.','');
}
```

but i don't know if it's correct

Comment: so, what are you asking?

Comment: i asking if it's correct or no

Comment: Is it working? If not then it's not correct.